# Connect to SSH in same network

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, vpn

I have server with vpn network, raspberry pi and my pc.
For some internet provider reasons, I can't access remotly my raspberrypi, opening ports don't work correctly.
So I decided to connect my PC to same network with vpn. I can access ssh of my raspberrypi from server, but can't from my pc.
Is it possible to access this device with my PC, if I am connected to this vpn network on my server too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding option *client-to-client* in server.conf in openvpn make work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding option client-to-client in server.conf in openvpn make work as
> expected.

Does it worked ?

On my side , `client-to-client` is not enough, and no more when I add `topology subnet` too.

Comment: Yes, after adding client-to-client working fine. I can share my server config too, maybe I have some additional options. Also dont forget to restart everything after change.

Comment: Oh I remember, add client-to-client BELOW every optiong in server.conf. That should work, I had problems, when option was above, I don't know why